# In Python, why isn't there a built in function to find a key in a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

To elaborate

```
sample_dict = {"key1" : {"key2" : "value_of_interest}}
```

Now I want to be able to make the following call

```
val = sample_dict.recursive_get("key2", None)
```

I can think of a number of cases where this would be useful. For example, getting a key-value from an api response that came as JSON.

And I know it is not difficult to write to such a function, but my question is - why is it not already included?

If it leads to bad design, please provide some examples.

Comment: What do you do when there are multiple sub dicts with `key2`, or when the top level dict itself has a `key2`?  There are too many possible cases to make one all encasing function reasonable. `sample.get('key1', {}).get('key2', None)` seems pretty straightforward.

Comment: _why is it not already included?_ Because [Explicit is better than implicit. Also, In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).

Comment: What should it do here? `sample_dict = {'key1': {'key1': 'value_of_interest'}}; val = sample_dict.recursive_get('key1', None)`

Comment: `dict[key1][key2]` if you dont know key1 just loop over the dict with `for k,v in dict.items()`

Comment: Or how about this? `sample_dict = {'key1': ['apple', 'orange', {'key1': 'value_of_interest'}, 'pear']}` Dicts (esp. formed form JSON) can take a lot of different forms.

Comment: This method would be specific to a particular use case of dicts, not applicable to a dict in general. It would be appropriate for a subclass of dict, but not `dict` itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose, as several commenters pointed out, the key pointing to your "value of interest" appears multiple times in the nested hierarchy:

```
sample_dict = {'key1': {'key1': 'value_of_interest'}}
val = sample_dict.recursive_get('key1', None)
```

What is the value of `val`? The inner dict? `'value_of_interest'`? What *should* it be? Which answer violates the [principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment)?

What about a dict like this?

```
sample_dict = {
        'key1': [
                {'key1': 'value_of_interest'},
                {'key2': 'less_interesting_value'},
                ],
        }
```

Should the recursion check at every level for a possible `list` or array? It's not uncommon to see dicts like this, especially when formed from JSON.

The point is there's a lot of different dicts out there, which can be nested in a lot of different ways. Python is pretty well-equipped to handle them all fairly elegantly. No definition of `recursive_get` that I can think of, though, is.

Answer (score 2):

```
def recursive(dic, key, out=[]):
    if out: return
    if key in dic: out += [dic[key]]
    for k, v in dic.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict): recursive(v, key)
    return out
```

think i wrote you a depth first search?

Comment: `isinstanceof` -> `isinstance`

Comment: You need to pass `out` in to the recursive `recursive` call of the work it does is discarded.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument i dont think so, though i did not run this code

Comment: It works because of the [most famous Python "gotcha"](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments). Function arguments are evaluated **once**. Every time `recursive` is called it's with a reference to the same list.